# Install clientside PDF editor with WebPack + npm: At all possible?

Tags: npm, webpack, jspdf, pdfkit, pdfmake

I want to create PDF's clientside (in the browser). I'm using WebPack to bundle my javascript application and npm to install the needed libraries. I've tried the following without success:

- pdfmake
- jspdf
- pdfkit

Has anyone here gotten this setup to work with any of these (or some other) libraries? Mind sharing how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdfmake-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake-client) which is a wrapper to the pdfmake library that serves the client build over npm.

In general pdfmake does have a client build but serves the node version over NPM, this is likely a good case for a PR for that project so it will serve the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get jspdf to work, but the version from npm didn't work.

First I ran **npm install jspdf --save**

Then I downloaded the the lastest code from https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

and ran **npm run build**

then I replaced node_modules\jspdf\dist\jspdf.min.js with the one I just built.

Then the following code worked

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

I'm using webpack and nothing needed to be added to the config

More samples of usage can be found here: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf